# How to parse/pull specific data out of a file with Python

Tags: regex, parsing, python-2.7, lua, slice

I have an interesting issue I am trying to solve and I have taken a good stab at it but need a little help.  I have a squishy file that contains some lua code. I am trying to read this file and build a file path out of it.  However, depending on where this file was generated from, it may contain some information or it might miss some.  Here is an example of the squishy file I need to parse.

```
Module "foo1"
Module "foo2"
Module "common.command" "common/command.lua"
Module "common.common" "common/common.lua"
Module "common.diagnostics" "common/diagnostics.lua"
```

Here is the code I have written to read the file and search for the lines containing Module.  You will see that there are three different sections or columns to this file.  If you look at line 3 you will have "Module" for column1, "common.command" for column2 and "common/command.lua" for column3.

Taking Column3 as an example... if there is data that exists in the 3rd column then I just need to strip the quotes off and grab the data in Column3.  In this case it would be common/command.lua.  If there is no data in Column3 then I need to get the data out of Column2 and replace the period (.) with a os.path.sep and then tack a .lua extension on the file.  Again, using line 3 as an example I would need to pull out common.common and make it common/common.lua.

```
    squishyContent = []
    if os.path.isfile(root + os.path.sep + "squishy"):
        self.Log("Parsing Squishy")
        with open(root + os.path.sep + "squishy") as squishyFile:
            lines = squishyFile.readlines()
        squishyFile.close()

        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("Module "):
                path = line.replace('Module "', '').replace('"', '').replace("\n", '').replace(".", "/") + ".lua"
```

Just need some examples/help in getting through this.

Comment: Seems like a simple regex: `^Module "([^"]*)"(?: "([^"]*)")?$`

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but the easiest approach is to convert everything you told us about your task to code.

```
for line in lines:
    # if the line doesn't start with "Module ", ignore it
    if not line.startswith('Module '):
        continue

    # As you said, there are 3 columns. They're separated by a blank, so what we're gonna do is split the text into a 3 columns.
    line= line.split(' ')
    # if there are more than 2 columns, use the 3rd column's text (and remove the quotes "")
    if len(line)>2:
        line= line[2][1:-1]
    # otherwise, ...
    else:
        line= line[1] # use the 2nd column's text
        line= line[1:-1] # remove the quotes ""
        line= line.replace('.', os.path.sep) # replace . with /
        line+= '.lua' # and add .lua
    print line # prove it works.
```

With a simple problem like this, it's easy to make the program do exactly what you yourself would do if you did the task manually.